# Find infimum or minimum of $\frac{\log_{a} b}{a-b+1}+\frac{\log_{b} c}{b-c+2}+\frac{\log_{c} a}{c-a+3}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms, contest-math

> If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers in the interval $(0, 1)$, find infimum or minimum of $$\frac{\log_{a} b}{a-b+1}+\frac{\log_{b} c}{b-c+2}+\frac{\log_{c} a}{c-a+3}.$$

I used AM-GM-HM inequality as follows:

$$\frac13 \left( \frac{\log_{a} b}{a-b+1}+\frac{\log_{b} c}{b-c+2}+\frac{\log_{c} a}{c-a+3} \right) \ge \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{(a-b+1)(b-c+2)(c-a+3)}} \ge \frac{3}{a-b+1+b-c+2+c-a+3}=\frac12$$

Thus

$$\frac{\log_{a} b}{a-b+1}+\frac{\log_{b} c}{b-c+2}+\frac{\log_{c} a}{c-a+3} \ge \frac32$$

Is this even possible? Because I couldn't solve for the equality condition, which is

$$\frac{\log_{a} b}{a-b+1}=\frac{\log_{b} c}{b-c+2}=\frac{\log_{c} a}{c-a+3}$$

Is there another way to see that the given expression indeed can take $3/2$?

Comment: The equality condition for the GM-HM is $$a-b+1=b-c+2=c-a+3,$$ which is equivalent to $c=a-1$, $b=a-1$. However, this is impossible as they are in $(0,1)$. Thus, $3/2$ cannot be obtained.

Comment: Oh, that is right. Thank you. So what is the minimum? Or maybe there is no minimum and 3/2 is infimum.

Comment: @Ghartal It seems the infimum is $\frac12\sqrt[3]{36}\approx 1.650963624$;

Comment: @River Li thanks. How did you get it? Can you please write it as an answer?

Comment: @Ghartal My solution is not nice. I will post it if no nice solution is given.

Comment: @Ghartal By the way, you put the tag "contest-math". What's the source of the problem?

Comment: @River Li sry for late response. I don't know the source of problem. But they sent it for me in a math contest preparation group. Thats why I put the tag.

Comment: @Ghartal Nice. I will post my proof soon.

Comment: @Ghartal I just give my proof. Hope to see nice proof.

Comment: I also wonder if there is a simpler approach. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Remarks:* The proof of (2) is quite complicated. We hope to see a nice proof.

**Fact 1**: Let $a, b, c \in (0, 1)$. Then
$$\frac{\log_{a} b}{a-b+1}+\frac{\log_{b} c}{b-c+2}+\frac{\log_{c} a}{c-a+3} > \frac12\sqrt[3]{36}.$$
(The proof is given at the end.)

On the other hand, letting ($z > 0$)
$$a = \mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{\sqrt[3]{36}}{2z}\right),
\quad b = \mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{\sqrt[3]{6}}{2z}\right),
\quad c = \mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{1}{z}\right),$$
we have $a, b, c\in (0, 1)$, and
$$\lim_{z\to \infty} \left(\frac{\log_{a} b}{a-b+1}+\frac{\log_{b} c}{b-c+2}+\frac{\log_{c} a}{c-a+3}\right)
= \frac12\sqrt[3]{36}. \tag{1}$$

Using Fact 1 and (1), we have
$$\inf_{a, b, c\in (0, 1)} \left(\frac{\log_{a} b}{a-b+1}+\frac{\log_{b} c}{b-c+2}+\frac{\log_{c} a}{c-a+3}\right) = \frac12\sqrt[3]{36}.$$
(*Note*: The infimum is not attained.)

---

---

**Proof of Fact 1**:

Using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\frac{\log_{a} b}{a-b+1}+\frac{\log_{b} c}{b-c+2}+\frac{\log_{c} a}{c-a+3}\right)
 \left((a - b + 1) + \frac{b - c + 2}{2} + 
 \frac{c - a + 3}{3}\right)\\
 \ge\,\,& \left(\sqrt{\log_{a} b}
 + \sqrt{\frac{\log_{b} c}{2}}
 + \sqrt{\frac{\log_{c} a}{3}}\right)^2.
\end{align*}
Also, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\sqrt{\log_{a} b}
 + \sqrt{\frac{\log_{b} c}{2}}
 + \sqrt{\frac{\log_{c} a}{3}}\right)^2\\
 =\,\,& \log_{a} b + \frac{\log_{b} c}{2} + \frac{\log_{c} a}{3}
 + 2 \sqrt{\log_{a} b} \sqrt{\frac{\log_{b} c}{2}}
 + 2 \sqrt{\frac{\log_{b} c}{2}}
 \sqrt{\frac{\log_{c} a}{3}}
 + 2\sqrt{\frac{\log_{c} a}{3}} \sqrt{\log_{a} b}\\
 \ge\,\,& \log_{a} b + \frac{\log_{b} c}{2} + \frac{\log_{c} a}{3}
 + 3\sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{\log_{a} b} \sqrt{\frac{\log_{b} c}{2}}
  \cdot 2 \sqrt{\frac{\log_{b} c}{2}}
  \sqrt{\frac{\log_{c} a}{3}}
  \cdot 2\sqrt{\frac{\log_{c} a}{3}} \sqrt{\log_{a} b}}\\
 =\,\,& \log_{a} b + \frac{\log_{b} c}{2} + \frac{\log_{c} a}{3}
 + \sqrt[3]{36}.
\end{align*}
Thus, we have
$$\frac{\log_{a} b}{a-b+1}+\frac{\log_{b} c}{b-c+2}+\frac{\log_{c} a}{c-a+3}
\ge \frac{\log_{a} b + \frac{\log_{b} c}{2} + \frac{\log_{c} a}{3}
 + \sqrt[3]{36}}{\frac23 a - \frac12 b - \frac16 c + 3}. $$

It suffices to prove that
$$\log_{a} b + \frac{\log_{b} c}{2} + \frac{\log_{c} a}{3}
> \frac12 \sqrt[3]{36}\left(\frac23 a - \frac12 b - \frac16 c\right) + \frac12 \sqrt[3]{36}. \tag{2}$$

We split into two cases:

**Case 1**: If $4a < 3b + c$, we have $\frac23 a - \frac12 b - \frac16 c  < 0$. Also, we have
$$\log_{a} b + \frac{\log_{b} c}{2} + \frac{\log_{c} a}{3}
\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\log_{a} b \cdot \frac{\log_{b} c}{2} \cdot \frac{\log_{c} a}{3}} =
\frac12 \sqrt[3]{36}.$$
Thus, (2) is true.

**Case 2**: If $4a \ge 3b + c$, using $\frac12 \sqrt[3]{36} < 5/3$ and $\frac23 a - \frac12 b - \frac16 c  \ge 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$\log_{a} b + \frac{\log_{b} c}{2} + \frac{\log_{c} a}{3}
> \frac{5}{3}\left(\frac23 a - \frac12 b - \frac16 c\right) + \frac{5}{3}.$$
Note that
$$
 \frac13 \log_a b + \frac13 \log_b c + \frac13 \log_c a
 \ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac13 \log_a b \cdot \frac13 \log_b c \cdot \frac13 \log_c a}
 = 1.
$$
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac23 \log_{a} b + \frac16 \log_{b} c + 1
> \frac53\left(\frac23 a - \frac12 b - \frac16 c\right) + \frac53. \tag{3}$$

**Fact 2**: If $1 > x \ge y > 0$, then
$\log_x y \ge \frac53(x - y) + 1$.
(*Proof*: Let $f(y) = \log_x y - \frac53(x - y) - 1$. We have $f''(y) = \frac{1}{y^2\ln(1/x)} > 0$ for all $y\in (0, 1)$. Using the convexity of $f$, we have $f(y) \ge f(x) + f'(x)(y - x) = (\frac{1}{x\ln x} + \frac53)(y - x) \ge 0$ where we have used $-\mathrm{e}^{-1}\le x\ln x < 0$ for all $x\in (0, 1)$.)

We split into three cases:

**Case 2.1**: If $a \ge b$ and $c \ge b$, (3) is written as
$$\frac23\left(\log_a b - \frac53(a - b) - 1\right) + \frac16 \log_b c + \frac{5}{18}(c - b) > 0. \tag{4}
$$

Using Fact 2, (4) is true.

**Case 2.2**: If $a \ge b \ge c$, (3) is written as
$$\frac23\left(\log_a b - \frac53(a - b) - 1\right) + \frac16\left(\log_b c - \frac53(b - c) - 1\right) + \frac16 > 0. \tag{5}
$$

Using Fact 2, (5) is true.

**Case 2.3**: If $b > a \ge c$,
it suffices to prove that
$$\frac23 \log_{a} b + \frac16 \log_{b} c + 1
\ge \frac53\left(\frac23 a - \frac12 a - \frac16 c\right) + \frac53. $$
Using Fact 2, we have
$$\frac16 (\log_a c - 1) \ge \frac53\left(\frac23 a - \frac12 a - \frac16 c\right).$$
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac23 \log_{a} b + \frac16 \log_{b} c + 1
\ge \frac16 (\log_a c - 1) + \frac53 $$
or
$$\frac23 \log_{a} b + \frac16 \log_{b} c - \frac16 \log_a c - \frac12 \ge 0$$
or
$$\frac{4\ln \frac{1}{b} - \ln \frac{1}{c}}{6\ln \frac{1}{a}}
+ \frac{\ln \frac{1}{c}}{6\ln\frac{1}{b}} - \frac12 \ge 0.$$

We split into two cases:

**Case 2.3.1**: If $4\ln \frac{1}{b} - \ln \frac{1}{c} < 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{4\ln \frac{1}{b} - \ln \frac{1}{c}}{6\ln \frac{1}{b}}
+ \frac{\ln \frac{1}{c}}{6\ln\frac{1}{b}} - \frac12 \ge 0$$
which is clearly true.

**Case 2.3.2**: If $4\ln \frac{1}{b} - \ln \frac{1}{c} \ge 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{4\ln \frac{1}{b} - \ln \frac{1}{c}}{6\ln \frac{1}{c}}
+ \frac{\ln \frac{1}{c}}{6\ln\frac{1}{b}} - \frac12 \ge 0$$
or
$$\frac23 \log_c b + \frac16 \log_b c \ge \frac23$$
or
$$\frac{(2\log_c b - 1)^2}{6\log_c b} \ge 0$$
which is clearly true.

We are done.